# Can we convert Sharepoint date/time to XSD date/time

Tags: 2013, list, date-time

I have requirement to convert SharePoint date and time to xsd date and time. can we do this in SharePoint. Any insights would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to change the way the date displays in SharePoint 2013. The formatting of dates and numbers can be changed by changing the locale in site settings, under site administration. You'll have to find a locale that works for you, I can tell you offhand that Lithuanian and Japanese locales format dates as YYYY-MM-DD.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ornery,. I am doing this integration project where source system is Sharepoint list and Destination is Netsuite ERP. When executing Post where items from sharepoint list is to be posted in Netsuite . In case of Datetime and column that i am trying to post, Netsuite throws error saying invalid datatime column. Doing research i found out. Netsuite only recognizes XSD datetime format. is there anything we can do in sharepoint to fix that.

Comment: Hey allegro, SharePoint uses the ISO datetime format. You will have to convert the datetime to XSD in code before executing the POST operation.

Comment: Is it possible OOTB to set Sharepoint Datetime format as XSD.

Comment: You can change how the datetime fields display within the UI, but I don't believe it's possible to change the format in which the datetime data is transferred and stored. You will have to convert the datetime to XSD in code before executing the POST operation to Netsuite.

Comment: Do you know how do we do that changing Datetime format to XSd using C#?